# Accessing users google drive without using Android Activities

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement an android app where the app uploads images to users google drive. I successfully implemented the quick start guide given [here](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/quickstart). It is uploading the images but all the examples/samples of uploading the image using android Activity. I went through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) provided by google but it is very loosely coupled.

Is there any example/sample which upload the file without using an activity so that later I could convert it into a background service?

I reached the following point. Now, at this point `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount` is returning null and I am looking for a solution where it picks the account and gets the permission from the user. In google sample it appears to do in  startActivityForResult. I tried to look for that too but there is no Drive REST v3 samples for Android.

```
package com.mpathak.drivetesting;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.CreateFileActivityOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveContents;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DriveSample {
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private DriveClient mDriveClient;
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;
    private Context _context;
    private static final String TAG = "drive-Testing";

    public DriveSample(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void uploadFile()
    {
        GoogleSignInClient GoogleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();

        mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(_context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(_context));

        mDriveResourceClient =
                Drive.getDriveResourceClient(_context, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(_context));

        saveFileToDrive();
    }

    private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                        .build();
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(_context, signInOptions);
    }

    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 10;

        final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/DCIM/Camera/some_image.jpg", options);

        mDriveResourceClient
                .createContents()
                .continueWithTask(
                        task -> createFileIntentSender(task.getResult(), image))
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        e -> Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.", e));
    }

    private Task<Void> createFileIntentSender(DriveContents driveContents, Bitmap image) {
        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");

        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
        try {
            outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.", e);
        }

        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet =
                new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                        .setTitle("Android Photo.png")
                        .build();

        CreateFileActivityOptions createFileActivityOptions =
                new CreateFileActivityOptions.Builder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                        .setInitialDriveContents(driveContents)
                        .build();

        return mDriveClient
                .newCreateFileActivityIntentSender(createFileActivityOptions)
                .continueWith(
                        task -> {
                            return null;
                        });
    }

}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 the documentation builds a signin client and uses startActivityForResult(GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN); so not sure what would be its alternative

Comment: True. I guess you'll need to login at least once to get an auth token

Comment: Hence not getting how to do that and move ahead

Comment: how do you suppose this can be achieved? try the rest api

Comment: @AdiMabfalin please see my edit